# How to efficiently store and read back a Hierarchy from cache

Tags: c#, performance, caching, redis, hierarchical-data

My situation is that I'm currently storing a hierarchy in a SQL database thats quickly approaching 15000 nodes ( 5000 edges ). This hierarchy is defining my security model based off a users position in the tree, granting access to items below. So when a user requests a list of all secured items, I'm using CTE to recurse it in the db ( and flatten all items ), which is started to show its age ( slow ).

The hierarchy is not changing often so I've attempted to move it into RAM ( redis ). Keeping in mind i have many subsystems that need this for security calls, and UI's to build the tree for CRUD operations.

**First Attempt**

My first attempt is to store the relationships as a key value pair
(this is how its stored in the database )

```
       E
     /   \
    F     G
   / \   /  \
  H  I  J    K

mapped to:
    E - [F, G]
    F - [H, I]
    G - [J, K]
```

So when i want E and all its decedents, i recursively get its child and their child using the keys, and it allows me to start at any node to move down. This solution gave a good speed increase but with 15,000 nodes, it was approximately 5000 cache hits to rebuild my tree in code ( Worse case scenario... starting at E. performance is based off the starting nodes location, resulting in super users seeing the worst performance). This was still pretty fast but seemed to chatty. I like the fact that i can remove a node at anytime by popping it out of the keys List without rebuilding my entire cache. This was also lighting fast to build a tree on demand visually on a UI.

**Second Attempt**

My other Idea is to to take the Hierarchy from the Database, build the tree and store that in RAM ( redis ) then pull the entire thing out of memory ( it was approx 2 MB in size, serialized  ). This gave me a single call ( not as chatty ) into redis to pull the entire tree out, locate the users parent node, and descend to get all child items. These calls are frequent and passing down 2 MB at the network layer seemed large. This also means i cannot easily add/remove and item without pulling down the tree and editing and pushing it all back. Also on demand trees building via HTTP meant each request had to pull down 2MB to only get direct children ( very small using the first solution ).

---

So which solution do you think is a better approach ( long term as it continues to grow ). Both are defiantly faster and take some load off the database. Or is their a better way to accomplish this that i have not thought about?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer an idea...

Use **hierarchical versioning**. When a node in the graph is modified, increment its version (a simple int field in the database), but *also* increment versions of all of its ancestors.

- When getting a sub-tree from the database for the first time, cache it to RAM. *(You can probably optimize this through recursive CTE and do it in a single database round-trip.)*
- However, the next time you need to retrieve the same sub-tree, retrieve only the root. Then compare the cached version with the version you just fetched from the database.

  - If they match, great, you can stop fetching and just reuse the cache.
  - If they don't, fetch the children and repeat the process, refreshing the cache as you go.

The net result is that more often than not, you'll cull the fetching very early, usually after only one node, and you won't even need to cache the whole graph. Modifications are expensive, but this shouldn't be a problem since they are rare.

*BTW, a similar principle would work in the opposite direction - i.e. when you start with a leaf and need to find the path to the root. You'd need to update the versioning hierarchy in the opposite direction, but the rest should work in a very similar manner. You could even have both directions in combination.*

**--- EDIT ---**

If your database and ADO.NET driver support it, it might be worth looking into server notifications, such as MS SQL Server's [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) or [OracleDependency](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDependencyClass.htm).

Essentially, you instruct the DBMS to monitor changes and notify you when they happen. This is ideal for keeping your client-side cache up-to-date in an efficient way.

Comment: Compared to my method, this requires less work when we are updating the node and more work when we read the node from the cache. I think it depends on when you want to show performance impact to users. I think its most logical to make tree-updating request more long to make following read requests faster, than to spread additional work across following reads.

Comment: @mephisto123 Not necessarily. The initial query is more expensive in my approach, but the subsequent queries will tend to be extremely cheap, usually just one row. In your approach, subsequent queries will still need to fetch the whole sub-tree, even when nothing changed. So, my approach is better if there are more repeated reads. BTW, you explode the database size - this cannot be good for the database-level caching, so even the performance of this first query is in question - a recursive CTE on a small well-cached database may well be faster than a fetch of an un-cached BLOB.

Comment: No, I did not mean to save whole subtree in database. I meant to cache  list of all descendant nodes (just simple array) since actual tree structure is not required often, most of the time we just need to know list of nodes below some selected node and nothing else. So if information for selected node is already cached, we will just do one simple request from cache and we're done.

Comment: @mephisto123 OK, perhaps I misunderstood you answer. When you say "cache", did you mean client-side? If so, the OP already tried that. The issue is not with initially building the cache, the issue is with detecting the stale data in the cache and avoiding the need to repeatedly fetch large amounts of data from the database (i.e. constantly rebuilding the cache from scratch).

Comment: @mephisto123 BTW, whether the cache is a tree or a list doesn't matter much - both can be traversed fairly efficiently. I'd stick with a tree though, because it contains inherently more information and (among other things) allows you to share potions of the tree between different nodes (and save RAM).

Comment: I don't see any problems with invalidating cache records for changed node and all its parent nodes.

Comment: @mephisto123 But how will you find **which** node is invalidated? You can't fetch only the "current" node, since the user permissions of that node depend on the whole sub-tree (or path to root, OP wasn't clear, but this doesn't really change the argument). It's quite possible that the node remains unchanged but some of sub-nodes are stale and need to be refreshed, so you'd end-up re-fetching the whole sub-tree. You'd effectively be fetching same rows over and over, despite the fact that only a small minority of them gets modified. My solution simply cuts you off from unnecessary fetching.

Comment: If position of some node is changed, it can only affect lists of descendants of parents. So we will need to invalidate cache for these nodes. And by the way, you don't even need to rebuild the cache for user if that user will not come online.

Comment: @mephisto123 *"If position of some node is changed, it can only affect lists of descendants of parents."* True, but how do you detect **which** one has changed? Any concurrent database session might be making these changes while your session is holding onto a stale data. *"So we will need to invalidate cache for these nodes."* Only if we are actually going to use that piece of cache. *"And by the way, you don't even need to rebuild the cache for user if that user will not come online."* Again true, and this is exactly what my approach does.

Comment: all you need is to just invalidate cache entries for changed node and its parent nodes when the node is being changed (you obviously know when it happens because it is beging changed by some code). under "invalidate" i mean remove from cache. that way some delay is possible between node change and invalidation of cache, but this is matter of milliseconds...

Comment: @mephisto123 You **don't** know it is being changed! That my whole point. Some other client application might be changing it concurrently in the database without you ever knowing about it, *unless* you explicitly look into the database. Hence my repeated question: how do you know **which** node needs fetching? You can obviously fetch the whole sub-tree, but that's hardly an optimal solution.

Comment: OP said he is using Redis for cache. It is shared between all client applications. So obviously invalidating cache entry in Redis will take instant effect in all clients.

Answer (score 1):

If hierarchy is not changed often, you can calculate whole list of items below for each node (instead of just direct children).
This way you will need significantly more RAM, but it will work lightning-fast for any user, because you will be able to read whole list of descendant nodes in single read.

For your example (I'll use JSON format):

```
E - {"direct" : [F, G], "all" : [F, G, H, I, J, K]}
F - {"direct" : [H, I], "all" : [H, I]}
G - {"direct" : [J, K], "all" : [J, K]}
```

Well, for superusers you will still need to transfer alot of data per request, but I don't see any way to make it lesser.

Comment: - If RAM is a problem, the keys could be set with a short TTL, which would flush inactive users soon after they log out.

Comment: - And if using redis sets as opposed to JSON or some other string for representing subnodes, many operations could be optimized to simple checks such as SISMEMBER, etc, to keep network traffic low. http://redis.io/commands#set

Answer (score 0):

We do something like this. We read the tree into memory, store it in the application cache, and access it from memory. Since our changes almost never, and changes don't have to be immediately reflected in the web app, we don't even bother to detect them, just let the cache age and get refreshed. It works really well for us.